# How to add a column to a file in azure synapse analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am still quite new to this but I was wondering how to add columns to a file?

[image: Image of pipeline]

In my pipeline, I initially receive my data from an API, I combine multiple files from the same API to form a large file. I have now received the task to add columns to this file because we are planning on having one set of columns and we require some additional columns to make this possible for other sources.

Right now I am using the default column names i.e. "Prop_0", "Prop_1" etc... Anyway to add columns easily?

Comment: you can [add additional column when using copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy)

Comment: Would I need to map out all my columns to add extra columns?

Comment: No, you can add in the source tab itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Click the `+new` in the additional columns in the source tab of copy activity.

[image]

- You can enter the name of the column and value of the column in the respective text boxes.
- Value of the column can be `static value`, `expression`, `$$filepath`,  `$$COLUMN:<source_column_name>`.

Refer [microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy) for more details on additional column during copy.

Comment: how would I assign a column named "AdditonalColumn1" with a staticValue like "Empty"? Sorry, I find some of this confusing.

Comment: Check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/7ZiFst6.png)